# Tensorflow VariableScope: original_name_scope vs name

Tags: python, scope, tensorflow

In TensorFlow, the `VariableScope` class has both a `original_name_scope` and `name` attribute. What are their differences and when should I use one over the other? I can't seem to find much documentation on them.

**Use case:**
I'm using the `tf.get_collection(key, scope)` method. Its second argument expects a string, but my variable `my_scope` has type `VariableScope`. I'm trying both

```
tf.get_collection(key, my_scope.name)
```

and

```
tf.get_collection(key, my_scope.original_scope_name)
```

. Both seem to work, but I'm not sure which is "right" and won't give me problems later down the road.

Answer (score 2):

`foo.name` returns the name (String) of the scope. On the other hand, `foo.original_name_scope` returns the same string as `foo.name`, except when the scope is recreated. In that case, all sub-scopes are appended with a `_#` as needed to make all calls to `foo.original_name_scope` return something unique for each instance of a scope.

For example, in this code:

```
with tf.variable_scope('a') as a:
    print(a.name)
    print(a.original_name_scope)
    print(a.original_name_scope)

with tf.variable_scope('a') as b:
    print(b.name)
    print(b.original_name_scope)
```

Returns

```
a
a/
a/
a
a_1/
```

Note that the calls to `original_name_scope` corresponding to different scope instances `a` return different values.

Presumably, this lets you distinguish between different scope instances with the same name.